# ag-grid version 18.1 doesn't support enableCellTextSelection anymore

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We want to disable the clipboard service of ag-grid. I stumble upon this flag `enableCellTextSelection` that is supposed to turn it off completely. But unfortunately it has no effect on the grid. In fact if I specify it as a direct property of `<ag-grid-angular>` It's throwing template parse error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'enableCellTextSelection' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
```

Which means it's not a valid property of the grid component. I can just directly add it to the `gridOptions`. But looking at the resolved `gridOptions.d.ts`, it is not listed there which means it's not a valid property of `gridOptions`.

Was it totally removed or was it replaced with another flag? Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: can you add some code to your question? your component where this fails and the module where AgGrid/this component are defined would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are asking about [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) version **`18.1`**, not `1.18`.

Seems like the property/feature was not there. It was introduced later.

Have a look at the documentation for `**v18.1**`: ***[Clipboard](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/18.1.0/javascript-grid-clipboard/)***

As per the [ChangeLog](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=22.1.0), it was introduced in **`v22.1.0`**

> AG-2729   *Feature Request*   Docs - Add example/document enableCellTextSelection: true

Comment: Haha yeah thanks for pointing out! I was asking about 18.1 and not 1.18. Accepted and +1.